# List Tabitems in a dropdownlist wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to display all the tab headers in a dropdownlist.I have implemented the tab and added the down arrow button to it. I added a popup to list the items along with the button. But i cannot find a way to bind the header of the tab items to the list in the pop (Name = PresetPopup). I have tried binding the itemsource of "ConnectionList". But the ConnectionList is not recogonized in the ConnectionPages.xaml.cs file. Any code how to bind this will be helpful. Or any other way to do this?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
<Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
<TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
<Border Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
<Grid>
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowDropDown"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" />
<ToggleButton Name="OpenPopupButton" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<ToggleButton.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
</ToggleButton.Style>
<materialDesign:PackIcon Background="White" Foreground="Black" Kind="ArrowDropDown" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" />
</ToggleButton>
<Popup Name="PresetPopup" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupButton, Path=IsChecked}"   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupButton}"    AllowsTransparency="True"   PopupAnimation="Slide"    StaysOpen="False" >
<ListBox Name="ConnectionList" ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectionsTab}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="a"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</Popup>
</Grid>
</Border>
</StackPanel>

<Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
<ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
</Border>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
...........
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Actually my final output requirement is similiar to this

[final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccoZU.png)

Comment: Is ConnectionsTab a property on your viewmodel? Is this viewmodel the DataContext of ConnectionPages.xaml ?

Comment: @o_w No, i don't have any view model for the tabs. I have it only in xaml. I add tabitems in it dynamically.I need to display all the tabs in the popup, since i need to restrict the number of tabs displaying. But i don't know how to bind it directly.

Comment: @o_w ConnectionsTab is the name of the TabControl in xaml

Comment: OK I see. Well you can't do ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectionsTab}" if the name ConnectionsTab is declared ouside the scope of the ControlTemplate. You want, I think, to do {Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}. Notice I added Items as the property on the control, to which you bind.